# How can I programmatically determine when an JavaScript AudioContext AudioBufferSource is done playing?

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

I am playing .MP3 files with the Web Audio API, and I am having trouble programmatically determining when the song is finished playing.

This is what I have:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

audioContext = new AudioContext();

source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.connect(audioContext.destination);

request.open('GET',url,true);
request.responseType='arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response).then(function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.start(0);
    });
}   
request.send();
```

This works well; I can start, stop, pause, and unpause a song with no problems.

What I want to do, however, is when a song stops playing upon completion (i.e., I have not called `audioContext.close()`), I want to call another function to set a message for the user. I have looked for some sort of callback I could leverage, I have tried the `finally()` of the `promise` provided by the `audioContext.decodeAudioData()` provides, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: @Wyck That worked, thanks! Now I see where I was missing information. On the MDN page for `AudioBufferSourceNode` under events it says "Inherits event handlers from its parent, AudioScheduledSourceNode." I just thought the link was going to send me to a generic event handler page; I had no idea it would take me to the events for `AudioBufferSourceNode`. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `ended` event of your `audioContext`. See [AudioScheduledSourceNode: ended event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event) for reference.

```
source.addEventListener('ended', () => {
   // done!
});
```

Or use the `onended` property.

```
source.onended = () => {
  // done!
}
```